# How to document.write image hyperlink inside getjson?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

Hi all i want to document.write a hyperlink image inside getjson i tried the following but it doesnt work. could you guys tell me what is wrong with my document write?

```
<script>  
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.somesite.com/handelit.ashx&callback=?', function(data){
      var siteContents = data.contents;      
      //writes to textarea  
      document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;  
      document.write("<a id="ok" href="http://www.mysite.com/master.m3u8?+siteContents+"><img src="./playicon.jpg"></a>");

    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console ? A 404 will make callback actually never called

Comment: I recommend spending an hour reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes an hour, and it shows you how to do fundamental things like interacting with the DOM after page load.

Answer (score 3):

> Hi all i want to document.write a hyperlink image inside getjson

You can't (not reasonably*). `document.write` only works during the initial parsing of the page. If you use it after the page finishes loading, it completely replaces the page.

Instead, interact with the DOM. Several ways to do that, but the most obvious based on your code is to have the anchor initially-hidden and then show it after filling in the text area like this:

```
$("#ok").show();
```

Full Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/azogid/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/azogid/1/edit)

*(I've changed the playicon.jpg to your gravatar, since otherwise it shows as a broken image on JSBin)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="myform">
    <textarea name="outputtext"></textarea>
  </form>
  <a id="ok" style="display: none" href="http://www.mysite.com/master.m3u8?+siteContents+"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f69cfb4677f123381231f97ea1138f8a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"></a>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.somesite.com/handelit.ashx&callback=?', function(data){
        var siteContents = data.contents;      
        //writes to textarea  
        document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents;
        // shows the link
        $("#ok").show();
      });  
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

* *"not reasonably"*: **IF** your content were coming from the same origin as the document (it doesn't look like it is), you could do this with a synchronous ajax call. But that would be very bad design.

Comment: thanks for reply. my main goal is to change the href value part with sitecontent variable.How i can do that? i get response back from getjson as it displays it in textarea ! i tried  document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = siteContents; but it changes the hyperlink url and the image of hyperlink doesnt show !

Comment: @user1788736: You mean the `href` on the anchor? You use [the `attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr) (or [the `prop` function](http://api.jquery.com/prop), in this *specific* case they mostly do the same thing).

Comment: brewal many thanks that is exactly what i wanted. It worked prefectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please, use createElement instead of document.write

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.somesite.com/handelit.ashx&callback=?', function(data){
      var siteContents = data.contents;      
      //writes to textarea  
      document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;  

      //Create A-Element
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.mysite.com/master.m3u8?' + encodeURIComponent(siteContents) );
      link.id = 'ok';

      //Append A-Element to your FORM-Element
      var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
      myForm.appendChild(link);

      //Create IMG-Element
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', './playicon.jpg');

      //Append IMG-Element to A-Element (id='ok')
      link.appendChild(img);
    });
```